# Azure Application Insights Visual Studio Solutions with Multiple Projects .Net Core 2. Showing Debug Telemetry only for One Project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-application-insights, .net-core-2.0

Here is the setup:

- Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.2) solution with one Web API project, and 4 Console Projects.
- All are .Net Core 2.0.
- Application Insights integrated with all of them as per the wiki at https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started-for-a-ASP.NET-CORE2.0-WebApp
- All of them point to the same AI resource.
- Solution is setup for multiple startup projects to start all the 5 projects.

**Issue:**
During debugging here is the observation:

- Visual Studio debug telemetry only shows telemetry from the API project. And doesn't show for the other 4 console apps.
- When I go to the Azure Portal, and search in the AI resource, I can see telemetry for the other 4 projects. Don't see for the API project.

What could I be missing? Have been struggling for a couple of days now...

Comment: Observed the Debug output in Visual Studio. Seeing that the telemetry is being generated for all projects. There is a difference for Web vs Console projects.
The telemetry for the WebAPI project starts with "Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured):"
For the Console projects, it starts with "Application Insights Telemetry:"

Comment: So it appears that VS doesn't think AI is configured for web project, and showing the telemetry locally only.
For console projects the telemetry is being sent to azure, and is not being shown locally.
I have strictly followed the instructions at https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started-for-a-ASP.NET-CORE2.0-WebApp to configure the WebAPI and Console projects.

Comment: Found the reason for "(unconfigured)" text in the WebAPI AI output. It was just because the appsettings.json was in wrong location. Fixed it and dont see the text anymore. The original issue still exists though.

Comment: On further troubleshooting, the original issue happens only when it is a combination of WebAPI + Console projects.
Just debugging two console projects together does not cause the issue.

Comment: WebAPI project outputs the telemetry starting with ""name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.7eccb92b0d144a698703a36b70d05f65.Event""
Console App outputs it as ""name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.7eccb92b0d144a698703a36b70d05f65.Event""
Notice the ".Dev" in the WebAPI output. VS is only showing those messages and ignoring the rest. 
Something related to Hosting Environment?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be your instrumentation key is not getting set for some reason. Can you try logging this property out to the console:

```
 Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey
```

That should be your key, if it's empty try posting what you have for your configuration setup for the api